# What does this symbols means on the LCD pin outs?

Tags: led, schematics, datasheet

I am trying to understand this product : NHD-C0220BIZ-FS(RGB)-FBW-3VM

[image]

It is a LCD with back light in reg, green, blue (not clear for me if they are mixed or you can only choose one)

What do you think that A , RK, GK, BA means? how I should connect it to the MCU and voltage?

Answer (score 2):

From the drawing, A is the anode and RK, BK, GK are the cathodes of the red/green/blue LEDs respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it

A is "Anode" ( + 3.3V in my case)
K is "Cathode" I connect it to the MCU pin, through a resistor. Setting the pin down, it will light the LED.

Comment: And by combining which of the three are on, you can have 8 colors (r,g,b,rg,rb,gb,rgb/white,off). And if you use pwm, you can get even more colors at the same time.